# How Can We see the running time in the screen when the Sleep is running

Tags: python-2.7

do i have the option to do time.sleep(300), and see the time running?
Instead of viewing screen that stuck till it's finish?

Comment: The short answer is not with `time.sleep` alone. The longer answer is that you would need threading to update in parallel with the sleeping process, or sleep for 1s at a time and update in-between.

Answer (score 1):

If precision is not too important you could do something like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from time import sleep

def sleep_counter(x):
    for i in range(x, 0, -1):
        print(str(i) + " seconds remaining in sleep.....", end='\r')
        sleep(1)
    print("All done...............................")

sleep_counter(300)
```

However, you should keep in mind that the print between each one second sleep will use up some small number of microseconds, so it will actually take a tiny bit longer than the number you specified (but probably not long enough to be noticeable for most purposes).

The `end='\r'` is to replace the new line characters that print automatically puts on the end of each line so that the line is replaced each time.

Note: the line replacement doesn't seem to work in IDLE, but works okay when running in the OS console.

---

Or for a slightly more elaborate version that formats the remaining time into hrs, mins and secs:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
from time import sleep

def sleep_counter(x):
    for i in range(x, 0, -1):
        hrs, mins, secs = 0, 0, 0

        if i > 60:
            mins = i / 60
            if mins > 60:
                hrs = i / 60 / 60
                mins = (hrs - int(hrs)) * 60
            secs = int((mins - int(mins)) * 60)
        else:
            secs = i

        hrs, mins, secs = str(int(hrs)), str(int(mins)), str(secs)

        print(hrs + " hrs " + mins + " mins " + secs + " secs remaining.....", end='\r')
        sleep(1)
    print("I'm awake.......................................")

sleep_counter(3665)
```

which gives you something like:

[image]

Note: to test with a large number e.g. 10,000 just change the sleep_counter param and change `sleep(1)` to something like `sleep(0.01)` and you will see it count down 100 times faster.